# How to destory the Admob adView completely and get the memory back?

Tags: android, admob

My app has an activity and a service. I recently introduce the Admob in my app.

However, I found it incredibly consuming the memory (5MB), and I can't get my memory back after destroy it.

I use this in my layout.xml

```
 <com.google.ads.AdView 
    android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    ads:adUnitId="xxxxxx"
    ads:adSize="BANNER">
```

Enable the admob in my onCreate

```
AdView adView = (AdView)this.findViewById(R.id.adView);
adView.loadAd(new com.google.ads.AdRequest());
```

Destory it on my onPause or onDestory

```
AdView adView = (AdView)this.findViewById(R.id.adView);
adView.destroyDrawingCache();
adView.destroy();
```

After destroy it, I still can't get my 5mb memory back. Can somebody help pls?

p.s. My service is running on the background and I could see the 5mb is still there.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure it's the admob view eating up all that memory?

Comment: Yes, when I remove adView.loadAd(new com.google.ads.AdRequest()), my 5mb is back. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tried other methods, none of them work. Also I'm using the latest Admob library 4.3.1.

The only solution works in my case is to call "System.exit(0)" somewhere in my app.

Then, the service will restart itself, and the memory consumed by Admob is also back.

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess but maybe try calling stopLoading() before calling destroy().

Comment: How about calling System.gc() after you've destroyed it?

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove the AdView from its container View so that the GC would be able to delete it.

Comment: I try to remove AdView from its parent View, but it's still not working. Thanks anyway.